# Running Django Project locally: cannot import settings module

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, import

I am trying to work on a friend's Django project. I've cloned his repo, and am having trouble running the project locally.

When I run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named settings
```

I am unsure if I am running into a problem because I have conflicting versions of Python installed, but I am unsure of how to proceed. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a `settings.py` file in the `<myproject>/<myproject>/` directory? The `settings.py` often contains secrets, so it might not always be checked in to the repository.

Comment: Do you have a `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable?

Comment: settings.py is in the .gitignore, I don't have it. Would getting that fix the problem?

Comment: @evanphamilton You definitely need `settings.py`. It is ok to include in your repo. Just don't have secret info in it if it is a public repo.